# Audio not working on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: sound, kde, 18.10

Audio has been working on my system (dual-booted windows and linux) for a while, but yesterday it just randomly started saying "No output or input devices found." I have tried suggestions everywhere on the web but nothing works. If I run `lspci` I get:

```
aayush@aayush-Satellite-L55-A:~$ lspci 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
aayush@aayush-Satellite-L55-A:~$
```

Please help me fix this. Thank you.

UPDATE: I found out using 'alsamixer' I can change volume and sond works but KDE Plasme doesn't do anything and doesn't recognize the sound card.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you get when you run `aplay -l`? Also what is the output of `sudo lshw -c sound`?

Comment: They both show that I have an audio device installed.

Comment: If you are seeing the hardware and alsa devices, and more importantly can hear sound when you play music files, I suspect there is something wrong with pulseaudio. Have you tried to reinstall it with `sudo apt purge pulseaudio && rm -rf /etc/pulse && apt install pulseaudio` and then reboot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just decided to reset my pc and that fixed it. I think maybe `pulseaudio` didn't install correctly. Thank you!